# Output multiple files from a single grep?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, zsh

I'm not very experienced in shell scripting, but I'm trying to understand how to grep for a pattern and for each file where there is a match write a file to disk that contains the matched line from grep. For example:

```
$ grep -E "MY PATTERN" myfile{1,3}
```

Then write out new files that contain the matching lines:

```
matches-myfile1
matches-myfile2
matches-myfile3
```

Is this possible? How can I do this? I'm looking for an answer is bash or zsh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bonsi has the right idea, but not the right approach (what should one do with filenames containing spaces or other whitespace characters, for example). Here is a way of doing it in `bash`:

```
for file in myfile{1,3}; do
    grep -E "MY PATTERN" < "$file" > "matches-$file"
done
```

If you *did* need to store the files you should account properly for word splitting, like so:

```
files=( myfile{1,3} )
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    grep -E "MY PATTERN" < "$file" > "matches-$file"
done
```

Comment: I fixed that flaw in his approach

Comment: Note that a difference with @Guru's approach is that if "MY PATTERN" is not to be found in myfile2 or if myfile2 doesn't exist or is not readable, then a matches-myfile2 will still be created (empty).

Answer (score 6):

One way using awk:

```
awk '/MY PATTERN/{print > "matches-"FILENAME;}' myfile{1,3}
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't think that this is possible  however it is possible to build a small script for that

```
#! /bin/bash
files=(file1 file2 file3)
for i in "${files[@]}"; do grep -E "MY PATTERN" < "$i" > matches-"$i"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with GNU find and GNU parallel:

```
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 grep '"MY PATTERN"' '{} > {//}/matches.{/}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `grep` output the filename with `-H`, and then use `awk` to write to it.

```
$ grep -H regexp files*  | awk -F : '{ file="matches-" $1; sub("^[^:]+:","",$0); print $0 > file; }'
```